# Should I delete my self-answered question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, self-answer, bad-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096911/how-to-create-a-storage-folder-for-java-files) a while ago back when I had little knowledge of how Java worked. Despite my best efforts to improve it, it has gotten significantly downvoted due to numerous technical inaccuracies.

The strange thing is that I self-answered it, and my answer got 1 upvote!

Normally, with such a downvoted question, I would just delete it. But I know Stack Overflow doesn't encourage deleting questions with a useful answer. On the other hand though, this is MY answer, so the only person losing reputation from this would be me.

Should I delete this heavily downvoted question with an upvoted self-answer?

Comment: Why no spend some time improving the question too, so that it meets the expectations of the site? Though the question doesn't have many close votes (1) so although it's been poorly received the lack of votes might be more indicative that it lacks research than anything else (I know nothing of Java other than a single module I did on in back in Uni many many years ago).

Comment: @JeanneDark yes, it's a duplicate, but the accepted answer on that question is wrong, so it is not an ideal duplicate.  Deleting a downvoted post doesn't count against the question ban any differently than it does when undeleted.

Comment: I think the intent of that answer, @psubsee2003, is that it means *"Deleting your down-voted questions counts against you (as well) as far as a question ban goes"*, it's saying that deleting it or not, they will contribute.

Comment: generally... a question that isn't deleted is better for you than one that is, regardless of its score.

Comment: @Larnu maybe.  To me it reads like the old misconception that deleting a downvoted post counts more than undeleted.

Comment: @Larnu I've already spent a LOT of time trying to improve the question. There's no way to improve a question with fundamental problems.

Comment: If you wish to delete it, I advise you to first delete your Answer, then your Question. As per my understanding the Question ban thinks of deleted Questions with Answers as worse than just deleted Questions, unless the post has been visible for 60 days, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I don't see much use for that question. The answer doesn't really answer the question, because it asks specifically about not using packages. And the question is a dupe of all those existing "declared package doesn't match expected package" questions, like [The declared package does not match the expected package ""](//stackoverflow.com/q/6997524).

Comment: @Tom Man, I wish somebody had told me about those questions... thanks.

Comment: Regarding *"However, please judge this question in the context of its answer"* ... this only works for very good and helpful answers to warrant a (historical) lock for the question, but this doesn't apply to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone! I have decided to follow Scratte's advice and delete my answer then my question. At least I'll get a badge out of it!